# How to add different types of ArrayLists into an Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have 4 ArrayLists of type String called A,B,C,D and I wanted to add them in an array. This is what I have tried so far but it doesn't work.

```
String[] finalWords = new String[]{A,B,C,D};
```

Comment: Do you want an array of `ArrayLists`, or to have one long array with the contents of all four `ArrayList`s?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the lists to a `List<List<String>>` and then use `Stream#flatMap` to flatten the lists into a single `List` which you can convert to an array as shown below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        List<String> list1 = List.of("a1", "a2", "a3");
        List<String> list2 = List.of("b1", "b2", "b3");
        List<String> list3 = List.of("c1", "c2", "c3");
        List<String> list4 = List.of("d1", "d2", "d3");

        List<List<String>> listOfLists = List.of(list1, list2, list3, list4);

        String[] finalWords = listOfLists
                                .stream()
                                .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                .toArray(String[]::new);
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalWords));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3]
```

**[Update]** Courtesy [Eritrean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722731/how-to-add-different-types-of-arraylists-into-an-array/62722902#comment110919136_62722902)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        List<String> list1 = List.of("a1", "a2", "a3");
        List<String> list2 = List.of("b1", "b2", "b3");
        List<String> list3 = List.of("c1", "c2", "c3");
        List<String> list4 = List.of("d1", "d2", "d3");

        String[] finalWords = Stream.of(list1, list2, list3, list4)
                                .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                .toArray(String[]::new);
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalWords));
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just Stream.of(list1, list2, ...) without creating a new list of lists.

Comment: @Eritrean - Brilliant! Let me incorporate this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Mandy8055 for the kind words.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in an ArrayList.

If your ArrayLists are of same type String, then

```
    List<List<String>> finalWords = new ArrayList();
   finalWords.add(A);
    finalWords.add(B);
    finalWords.add(C);
     finalWords.add(D);
```

If they are of different types, replace the type “String” above with “Object”.  But remember, you will have to cast them to read their correct type.

Comment: You cann't chain the calls of `List#add` method because it returns a boolean and not the result list.

Comment: Correct, I totally messed that up, I will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

As much as I jump at the chance to use *`java.util.stream.Stream`* every chance I get, no answer about arrays of parameterized types is complete without [*this crafty vararg idiom*](https://ideone.com/ykW21n) *`<T> List<T>[] toArray(List<T> ... lists){…}`*…

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.util.List.of;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<String> A = of("a", "ah", "A", "ay");
        List<String> B = of("B", "b", "bee", "Bea");
        List<String> C = of("sea", "Cee", "C++", "c", "Si", "C#");
        List<String> D = of("D", "d", "dee", "Di", "Dee-Dee Ramone", "Sunny D");
        
        List<Number> N1 = of(777);
        List<Number> N2 = of(-93.11D);
        List<Number> N3 = of(867.5f);
        List<Number> N4 = of(-309L);
        
        List<String>[] litzs = toArray(A, B, C, D);
        
        List<Number>[] nzs = toArray(N1, N2, N3, N4);
        
        /*...use them however...*/  

    }
    
    private static <T> List<T>[] toArray(List<T> ... lists){ 
        return lists;
    }
}
```

It might not be something Joshua Bloch would endorse. But it's a pretty neat little hack, just the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also

```
List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
Stream.of(A,B,C,D).forEach(finalList::addAll);
String[] finalWords = finalList.toArray(new String[0]);
```